# How long can Crew Dragon stay at ISS?

Tags: spacex, iss, crewed-spaceflight

It [appears](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/02/historic-crew-dragon-flight-now-targeted-for-an-early-may-launch/) that the first manned Crew Dragon flight to ISS may be extended due to there being only one US astronaut there.

> NASA is also trying to determine how long Dragon's first crewed mission will take. Initially, the space agency had planned to dock the capsule to the space station for about a week before Hurley and Behnken returned to Earth. Now it wants to extend that mission so the pair of astronauts can do more work on orbit.
>
> Later this spring, after NASA astronauts Jessica Meir and Drew Morgan return to Earth, only Chris Cassidy will remain on board the station. NASA would like to minimize the time Cassidy remains the lone US astronaut on board the orbiting laboratory, so there is discussion of extending Hurley and Behnken's mission to six weeks, or even three months.

Soyuz has a [200-day limit](https://spacenews.com/the-worlds-only-ride-to-the-international-space-station-is-grounded-what-now/). Is the maximum time on orbit known for Crew Dragon?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The NASA requirement is 210 days.  This is based on a nominal 180 day crew rotation.

[image]
[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120328055242/http://commercialcrew.nasa.gov/document_file_get.cfm?docid=107)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP did not ask what is the contractual minimum requried by NASA, they asked how much Crew Dragon can stay at the ISS which is independent of any paperwork done by NASA it's a measure of how it deteriorates with time. Is there any information about that?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta but doesn't the CD have to meet NASA's contractual requirements?

Comment: I don't think there can be a better answer. Dragon is rated & presumably tested to ensure it can be docked for 210 days. While it may be capable of more, nobody is going to go ahead and prove that.

Comment: Paperwork is **everything** in space. A new limit would need new paperwork.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta so are you asking for evidence that SpaceX misrepresented the capabilities of Crew Dragon to NASA in order to win that contract? Getting a real Woodward & Bernstein vibe going here...

Comment: I think the point being made is that the Dragon might be able to stay longer than required. If so, how much longer? a year? I remember there is a reason the soyuz is limited to 200 days and that had to do with the storability of some compound on board, hypergolic fuel or something. But I couldn't find the reference. Maybe this question could be addressed by asking what compounds are on the Crew Dragon, and what are their shelf lifes?

Comment: @JohnnyRobinson This is exactly what I'm saying. Soyuz has a **physical limit** due to deterioration of chemical compounds. Does Dragon have any similar issue that limits their lifetime in space to 210 days? Or there are no such issue and it could stay attached to the ISS for years without having any such issues? Or does the fuel used keep stable for, say 400 days instead of 200? NASA put the minimum they wanted on paper to ensure 180days crew rotation + 1 month of safety margin, but as far as we know Dragon can stay 10 years in space and still come back to Earth without issues.So which is it?